# Reasons to implement lazy loading in a Vue Single Page Application?

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, vuex, single-page-application, vue-router

I understand lazy loading will improve initial load times in a SPA, but just how much realistic benefit would I get out of it with a Vue application if I used Vue-router, Vuex and many components.

Do the performance benefits of lazy loading a Vue SPA come close to minifying and bundling code (in my case, with gulp)?

I understand if I upload hundreds of MB of media content in nested pages that the initial load-time benefit would be there, but I am wondering as to the need for a general use case.

All answers appreciated.

Comment: This is highly subjective but if your app has areas or sections that are visited by different audience segments, then you can reduce initial load time for each at the expense of a very small delay when navigating (and only when visiting an area for the first time). Also, why on Earth are you using Gulp when the Vue CLI skeleton sets you up with Webpack?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @phil, I use Gulp at the moment as it is part of the code base I work on for my employer. When you mention highly subjective, can you give me any reasons why someone would strongly disagree with you? Other than the complexity with setting up lazy loading in the first place (to learn how to do it).

Comment: Subjective on the purpose of the app, the audience, expectations on loading times, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team I work for use it to load large external javascript packages only when they are needed.

Imagine a project has five javascript visualization libraries all 1Mb each, but the home page is just a normal document, full of text. We don't want to make visitors who are just here to read text updates of our site to have to load [`three.js`](https://plotly.com/), [`plotly`](https://plotly.com/), etc if they aren't going to use it.

Webpack also [supports lazy loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), so you can still minify and bundle while lazy loading. It's just a bit of extra work to set up and debugging becomes a little harder.

I couldn't say how much benefit you'd get in your app but it worked well for us in a nested site (reduced the initial bundle size by half for us). I would check what bundle portions in Mb of your site is needed on the page load vs later because you will get big savings there.

**Discliamer**:
I'm not an expert in this topic, just sharing my experience over the last year of working on a massive web app where performance is an issue

Comment: Thanks @Jesse for your info, especially the halved loading time result